# How to apply a style to a table which has the Border property with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have 2 tables and want (using jQuery) to add the class: **border-width-1** to all **td** elements to the table which **border** property is not 0. In the example below this code would add the class: **border-width-1**  to all **td** elements in table **id="table-1"**

```
    Having these tables 
        <table border="1" id="table-1">
        <tr>
        <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
        </tr>
        </table>

           <table border="0" id="table-2">
            <tr>
            <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
            <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
            </tr>
            </table>

        After execution this would be the results: 
            <table border="1" id="table-1">
            <tr>
            <td class="border-width-1">row 1, cell 1</td>
            <td class="border-width-1">row 1, cell 2</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
```

I don't know how to target a element property with jquery. That's why I can't begin to write a function.

Comment: Though answers show how to select these, i would recommend to use id/class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is your code:

```
   jQuery('table[border!="0"] td').addClass('border-width-1');
```

Comment: Yes, because of the wrong parenthesis try last modification now it's ok